# Using SharePoint REST to add list item using C#

Tags: c#, rest, sharepoint-2013

I have an application hosted on one server that's not a part of my SharePoint farm. I need it to to post a new list item to a SharePoint List.  The Default SharePoint Zone (where it will be posted to) is configured to use Claims Authentication, Integrated Windows Authentication.

The identity that the application is running under has full administrative access over the list that I'm trying to post to.  Every time I post I get a "403 forbidden" error.  If I remove the endPointRequest.credentials line I get a 401 error.

```
    var data = "{'__metadata':{'type':'SP.Data.SpecialListItem'}, 'Special':'" + txtSpecial + "'}";

    HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://portal/_api/web/List/GetByTitle('Special')");
    endpointRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    endpointRequest.Method = "POST";
    endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    endpointRequest.ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose";

    endpointRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(endpointRequest.GetRequestStream());
    writer.Write(data);
    writer.Flush();

    using (HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(endpointResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```